# Did it really take until 1990 for "Europe"/UK to switch from glass bottles of milk to cartons?

Tags: europe, technology, food

I came across this weird claim: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_delivery#Europe

> By 1975, 94% of milk was in glass bottles, but in 1990, supermarkets started offering plastic and carton containers, reducing bottled milk from 94% to 3% by 2016.

Tetra Pak is from 1951. Why would they have sat around on this invention for 39 years before starting to use it?

And 3% still in 2016? I have never seen a glass bottle of milk in my life. This cannot be accurate.

If it actually turns out to be true, why would they have soda cans and Tetra Paks but not use them for milk specifically? Why insist on the fragile and heavy glass bottles for milk?

Comment: I can't speak for the whole of Europe but in the UK daily milk delivery to the door was very common. The bottles were directly recycled, the deliveryman would collect them as he delivered the milk and return them to the dairy where they would be cleaned and refilled.

Comment: In Germany carton containers have been the norm since at least the 1970's. In Berlin, I have never heard that milk delivery was ever offered due to the large amount of apartment buildings with locked front doors.

Comment: In the UK milk tends not to come in Tetra-Paks but in plastic bottle like things https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_milk_container

Comment: I'm Dutch, grew up during the 70s. Before the 70s we used bottled milk. For a while we used bags of milk, during the early 70s. After that most milk was sold in cartons.

Comment: Why is this weird?

Comment: France, growing up in the 80's I remember only plastic and carton cans from the supermaket - and a metallic can that I brought directly to the nearby farm for refill  !

Comment: Glass mainly is seen & often marketed as 'more eco-friendly' (which on terms of recycling it is, though indeed much too too heavy for transport… etc). It has some other advantages, & cons. Many people do prefer it this way, or are simply rejecting any plastics, etc. Therefore its market share in quite a few sections/regions etc is actually increasing again for quite a while now?

Comment: This question seems to contain more astonishment than research. I agree with @RedSonja, I'm not sure why this is surprising, noteworthy, or why it needs explanation.  I think there is an undocumented assumption; without sharing that assumption, I wouldn't know how to start to research the question.

Comment: @MCW It's worse. "Did it really take until 1990 for UK to reduce glass bottles of milk to 3% market share?" As the WP page is UK-only at that point, which was/is a lot different from the rest of Europe. And the assumption is: glass=old, carton is new/better, 'why were those English so obstinate in 'adopting it''? No prior research, false assumptions, teleology, misleading for 'Europe'… It's 'unclear & needs details', -> VtC, As or not.

Comment: Milkmen are a great institution. They don't just save on tetrapacks, they visit every street, every day. They are often the first people to report burglaries or old people having tumbles. They will actually knock and come in to check on granny.

Comment: Glass is 100% recyclable. Tetrapaks end up in landfills.

Comment: Glass bottles are easy to REUSE (but not recycle), in some countries you got discount for turning in empty bottles, so they did not end up in trash (in some countries it applied to ALL bottled products, i.e. beer, alcohol, soft drinks etc.). That reduces waste considerably, but has issues with cleaning used bottles. Plastic bottle (or bag) or tetrapack is easier to keep sterile (during whole packaging life cycle) and is much lighter and durable, so it was really a choice coming down to food safety and shopper's convenience. FYI, best material to recycle is aluminum, but obviously has issues.

Comment: You might like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuYLgEstc1Y as an illustration of why cartons took time to be widely used.  Also worth noting that tetrapak and other cartons were more suitable for long-life UHT milk bought in bulk as commonly drunk in continental Europe than for fresh pasteurised milk bought daily as commonly drunk in the UK.

Comment: "Milkmen are a great institution" UK folklore has it that they make themselves useful to couples where the husband is infertile, only he doesn't know about it.

Comment: When I was a child c. 1975 we received bottles delivered by the milkman, he took the empties away. Milk in supermarkets even then was in tetrapaks. MIlk delivery died off a lot until a few years ago and we see regular deliveries now that are mostly done at night, @shoover tetrapaks do not end up in landfill if you put them out for the council recycle / refuse collection, they have been recyclable for  donkey's years

Answer (score 9):

At this point, the 94% of UK milk sales in glass bottles was not sold in shops, but rather delivered via a local subscription scheme using fully recyclable containers delivered by electric vehicles. Honestly, add an app and it'd sound like a startup pitch from a couple of years ago.

Glass bottles are indeed relatively heavy and awkward - but this is only a problem if you have to carry them home from the shops. Once they're at your door, the disadvantages are much less. If you drop it in your kitchen, you're having a bad day whether it's in smashed glass or broken-open card.

The van collected empties as it delivered fresh ones. Glass could be reused extensively, and the net cost of cleaning and refilling was less than filling card containers. It worked out well - the shift away from it was as much due to changing shopping habits as anything else.

Comment: Glass is heavy _all the way,_ increasing transport costs through the entire production and delivery chain, like: 'increasing emissions' (as on over-focussed complaint would read nowadays). Strange thing about the options is that the [plastic-_bag_ option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_bag) does _technically_ meet the most checks for 'sweet sopt': shelf-life, costs, hygiene, etc. Bags using _way_ less resources than tetrapaks all around! Also much easier/better to recycle than cartons! (Consumer may want to invest in one holding container and a clip for sealing; but that's it)

Comment: Meaning: an explicit frame challenge is in order. "Did it _take_" 'from glass to carton' is not 'the teleological march of progress' the Qtitle seems to imply. As it would not be 'from glass to plastic jug'. There are _still_ different options, some technological developments, but also infrastructure, cost, environment concerns, consumer choice & preferences to observe. Plus the usual marketing: either glass or pak ads emphasisie 'I'm better, coz…'

Comment: @LangLangC Plastic bags used to be a pain in the ass because they broke easily. They are also somewhat impractical to put into a shopping bag and they look less attractive than a tetra brick.

Comment: @LangLangC if memory serves, it was common for the glass to not be transported very far - the collection/refilling points were near the end users, and the milk was brought to them in bulk. So the transport penalty was less than you might expect had it been a central bottling plant shipping the filled containers.

Comment: @Andrew Of course, even for dairy the centralisation tendencies are visible. The weight still is applicable to _all the way,_ and every step involved, only showing that the penalty for large central filling stations is even bigger now than for 'smaller circles' (or good ol days ;) A real point however is that centralised this weight can be offloaded to cost/price, easily, while the consumer 'picking it up' makes real _'lifting_ pounds' calculations whether 'carrying from store' or 'from door step'… in actual kgs?

Comment: The use of milk floats had the startling effect that the majority of all electric vehicles in the world across the 20th century were in the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 5):

> ***Q:*** Did it really take until 1990 for "Europe"/UK to switch from glass bottles of milk to cartons?

No. This is all based on flawed premises.

Additionally, this is nowhere about anything 'Europe', but simply Wikipedia misleading its readers with taking the situation in the UK as a pars pro toto for Europe. Which would be bad enough on its own, but made much worse by mixups it contains.

The bit quoted [from Wikipedia is misquoting its sources:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_delivery#Europe)

> ***Q:*** By 1975, 94% of milk was in glass bottles, but in 1990, supermarkets started offering plastic and carton containers, reducing bottled milk from 94% to 3% by 2016.

But the source says *nothing* about "started in 1990", says *nothing* about 'carton' or 'TetraPak', at all, but instead gives this account about the 'comeback of the glass bottle':

> Yet by the 1990s major supermarkets had switched to cheap plastic bottles, buying in bulk to drive down prices, and leaving the milkie struggling for business. […]
>
> In 1975, 94 per cent of milk was put into glass bottles, but that had fallen to under three per cent by 2016. However despite ongoing slumps in sales of cow milk, as people switch to nut, rice and soya options, the market for glass bottles milk appears to be holding steady, and even slightly increasing.
>
> — Sarah Knapton: ["Milk floats and glass bottles make a comeback as shoppers shun plastic"](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2018/01/21/milk-floats-glass-bottles-make-comeback-shoppers-shun-plastic/), The Telegraph,  21 January 2018.

Thus, before asking about anything like the implications found in the question, we need much better statistics to base our inquiry on, better than this unreliable snippet from Wikipedia.

Since Wikipedia says nothing really about 'Europe', but solely about market shares of containers for milk in the UK, with the source for that horrible snippet being seemingly more precise, but still very wobbly, a better statistic might inform us with:

| Year | Glass bottle | Paper cartons | Plastic bottles/pouches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | 94 | 6 | — |
| 1980 | 88 | 12 | — |
| 1985 | 80 | 20 | — |
| 1988 | 72 | 25 | 3 |
| 1991 | 65 | 19 | 16 |
| 1994 | 32 | 23 | 45 |

> Table: Shares of UK liquid milk market by container type (%), Source: EU 2005
>
> — Paul Vaughan, Matthew Cook & Paul Trawick: "A Sociology of Reuse: Deconstructing the Milk Bottle", Sociologia Ruralis, Vol 47, No 2, April 2007. pp.120–134, [doi](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9523.2007.00432.x)

Or in an updated graphic:

> [image]
>
> — Sarah Greenwood et al.: "Buy the product but rent the packaging – making reusable plastic packaging mainstream", in: UK Plastics Circular Network (ed): "Plastics Research and Innovation Fund Conference—Creative Circular Economy Approaches to Eliminate Plastic Waste", 2020, pp.26–37. [pdf](https://www.ukcpn.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/PRIF-Conference-Brochure-Final-1.pdf)

So the *start* of TetraPak-like cartons was even in the UK not really only *'started* in the 1990s'?

More important: the UK is known for coming up with it and keeping it going for much longer than elsewhere, especially 'in Europe': *fresh* milk delivery to the front door. The above table shows total market share for *consumer* milk containers. Which does include pasteurised and long-shelf-life products. And in the UK for quite a while the milk was still delivered fresh to the home in substantial proportions, not so much store-bought as it was in most of the rest of Europe much earlier. Store-bought milk in the UK saw 'glass-alternatives' earlier than the Wikipedia-quote suggests. UK's milk delivery kept glass usage for that milk system much higher than elsewhere.

A note on environmental effects for different container types: here glass bottles. Most recent studies *modelling* the effects of heavy to transport glass containers are assuming a reuse-rate of 8. And conclude in their *models:* plastic is better for carbon emissions. The above makes its *model* run the consumer milk bottle to be re-used 280 times! Which, I am sure it is mere coincidence, shows that glass is by far the most eco-friendly transport vessel. ;)
As with all models, and especially the mathematical ones giving you an illusion of precision, re-sing that Kraftwerk song about a model: 'and she's *looking* good'…

So, in light of having a nice system in place, very convenient and  with perfectly suitable for the task materials, perhaps the question should be re-phrased to: 'why did they UK start to switch away from the milkman delivery system with glass bottles, at all, in these proportions, let alone with this specific timeline?'

The most important UK-specific aspects are summarised as:

> Barriers to Reuse
>
> Throughout the food and drink industry, the introduction of plastic as a packaging material has brought new capabilities. Plastics ‘plasticity’ has enabled milk bottles to be shaped with a handle making it easier to carry and pour. The ability to create bottles of a larger size coupled with developments in domestic refrigeration has allowed milk to be sold in bulk and stored for longer in the home. Purchasing milk in higher volumes reflects a wider social trend of bulk shopping instead of daily grocery shopping as the supermarket superseded the milkman. In 2016, almost two-thirds of milk purchases were in a four pint or two-litre container, whilst only 4.9% were bought in the traditional doorstep pint size.
>
> A report on refillable glass container systems reported that “the traditional one pint refillable glass milk bottle [was] not suited for the retail shelves”. Indeed, whilst glass was a valued material for packaging products, it also had its critics. Marks and Spencer’s Packaging Department offers an insight of the emergence of plastics (specifically PET) and its relationship with glass. Compared to plastics, glass packaging contributed considerably to the overall weight of the product, thus reducing the overall potential spend in store. Glass was also prone to breakage and doorstep milk bottles were susceptible to slipping through the fingers. Plastic on the other hand, if dropped, would not smash or cause damage in the home.
>
> The return system of glass bottles was also a victim of social and cultural changes. With the increase of women in the workplace, milk was often left out on the front porch all day if delivered too late. Between 1993 and 1996, liquid milk consumption fell by 14%, which Ward attributes to traditional products such as milky drinks, rice pudding and custard being replaced by pre-prepared convenience foods. Dietary issues related to animal fats also changed the public perception of milk resulting in the more diverse milk market that we see today.
>
> During a sitting on the ‘Milk-based Drinks Regulations’ (1983), doorstep delivery was highlighted as being paramount for the elderly, the mother and her young children and those without easy access to supermarkets. Whilst doorstep delivery was a highly effective means of selling goods then, when car ownership and public transport infrastructure were limited, people now generally have better access to supermarkets.
>
> Market factors, particularly the deregulation of the Milk Marketing Board (MMB) in 1994, accelerated the demise of ‘the daily pinta’. The MMB’s main activity was the collection and sale of milk in England and Wales. The 1980s and 1990s were a time of radical change within the milk market with the Conservative Government’s privatisation and the Board’s incompatibility with the EU regime. During this period, large producers sought to sell to the supermarket groups directly, avoiding the scheme entirely. With its deregulation in 1994, its successor ‘Milk Marque’, a voluntary cooperative, controlled 65% of the milk in England and Wales. Criticised as an unregulated farmer-owned monopoly, Andrew Dare, chief executive of Milk Marque argued that the non-profit-making co-operative provided a vital service in striving to pay dairy farmers a fair return. In the summer of 1995 a pint of supermarket milk sold at 28p, whilst a four-pint plastic bottle cost only 22p a pint. In comparison, doorstep delivery milk sold for between 36p and 41p per pint. Referring to this disparity, Dixon highlights that supermarkets were able to reduce the price of milk for the consumer by removing the cost of the delivery service.
>
> Leading dairies reacted to and arguably accelerated the transition of milk sold in plastic bottles in supermarkets. For example, Northern Foods restructured their business reducing their glass-bottling capacity and contracting the doorstep market whilst continuing to invest in the supermarket sector. Developments in the milk industry supported the centralisation of bottling and the operation of scale economies. Major capital investment focused on product and packaging innovation in developing close relationships with major multiple retailers. Refrigerated storage and transport improvement throughout the supply chain increased the shelf life of milk and enabled plastic bottles to be rolled onto lorries, into supermarkets and then directly into supermarket aisles.
>
> Enablers of Reuse
>
> Today, the majority of milk is sold in plastic bottles from the supermarket, however bottled milk in glass has retained or acquired positive associations in terms of provenance, citizenship, sustainability and convenience.
>
> Today's doorstep Milk Deliverers argue that their milk is fresher, superior in taste and has provenance compared to supermarket milk. Tracing this back, the doorstep pint has regularly been associated with a rural idyll, coming from local farms via a regional diary whilst milk from supermarkets is associated with a larger nationalised distribution scale. The glass milk bottle then communicates traceability and some consumers are happy to pay more in support of British farmers. Vaughan et al. also highlight that consumers continue with the milkman service as a way of keeping him employed and to provide social functions such as keeping an eye on the elderly.
>
> The glass milk bottle is generally regarded as one of the most environmentally friendly forms of packaging, which became ever more important with the emergence of its plastic competitor. Many environmental groups saw the transition from reusable glass to plastic as a retrograde step. Most recently, the ‘Blue Planet Effect’ has contributed to customers moving back to the glass bottle.
>
> — Greendwood; amply referenced and really hitting most points mentioned in many comments on this page…

Comment: When living in England 1972/73, it was common place where we lived in a house in St. Albans for it to delivered. When staying in London (Bayswater) with my cousin, it was not delivered (to my knowlage) and it was bought in a bottle, which was mostly what was offered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the situation in the UK should have much relevance for the rest of a whole continent without (at that time) free trade, but anyway: Both East and West Germany had [milk in plastic bags](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milchschlauch) from the 1960s or 1970s on. Milk in (tetraedrical) tetra paks was available in East Germany since [at least the 1970s](https://brandenburg.museum-digital.de/index.php?t=objekt&oges=37223). On the other hand super markets in Germany even today usually offer some of their milk (the relatively untreated and more expensive variety) in glass bottles.

If you read the [wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetra_Pak) about Tetra Pak, you will find out that tetra paks were a) invented *in Europe* in the 1950s and b) used for *milk and milk products* from the very beginning. So the answer to the question is "definitely not".

Comment: Milk in glass bottles was reintroduced in Germany because consumers wanted to help save the planet. It started with the "bio" niche market but now there are many producers who offer bottles. It cost a few cents more but obviously some consumers are willing to pay. In fact some companies also sell yogurt and cream variations also in bottles. The bio niche, meanwhile, has started offering things normally seen in tins, e.g. vegetables, in jars.

Comment: @RedSonja "Help…", 'so they thought'. Different calculations & different _scenarios_ reveal different results for what would be best for that (scenarios implies: 'it's complicated'…really, really complicated, without easy clear answers). And often the simple _bag_ made from PE is the winner… You also see eco-/organic-, plus _fake_-'natural' items, and decidedly just _upmarket_ items ('ouhu, it's heavy, must be good') playing on that trend. ('Real ecos' now go for 'no packaging at all please'…)